# select the x0 (initial point for x ) in the curve fitting with lsqcurvefit

Tags: matlab

I wanted to fit an arbitrary function ( (k_plus-k_t*(1-exp(-k_plus/(a*k_t+b*k_d)))-k_d*(exp(-k_plus/(a*k_t+b*k_d)) to my data set. Therefore, I used lsqcurvefit in MATLAB. 
The code was  as follow:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
%% assign the anon function to a handle
k_plus =[0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 1 1.1 1.2 1.5 1.7 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 5];
K_minus_d = [0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 1 1.1 1.2 1.5 1.7 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 5];
K_minus_t =[ 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.7 1 1.1 1.2 1.5 1.7 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 5];
f1= sprintf('table%02d.txt',1);
data=tblread(f1);
x1=data(:,1);
x1=x1';
F=@(c,xdata)(xdata-K_minus_t*(1-exp(-xdata/(c(1)*K_minus_t+c(2)* K_minus_d)))- K_minus_d*(exp(-xdata/(c(1)*K_minus_t+c(2)* K_minus_d)))
x0 = [0.1 0.1];
[c,resnorm,~,exitflag,output] = lsqcurvefit(F,x0,k_plus,x1)
figure;
hold on
plot(k_plus,x1,'r-', 'LineWidth', 1)
plot(k_plus,F(c,k_plus),'-b*','LineWidth', 1,'MarkerSize', 1)
hold off
grid on;
```

I wonder how can I select the x0 (initial point for x) because I got different value for C when I change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're getting different values for c depending on your choice of the initial x0 and you want advice on how to choose a good initial value.
This is something that is hard to answer without sufficient knowledge about the function you are trying to fit. Is it describing experimental data? If so, you should have some expectations about what x should approximately be.
But it can very well be the case that there is no unique solution for your equation or that the solver gets stuck in a local minimum.